# Trigger Jenkins build via push to a specific branch on GitLab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, webhooks

If there is the way to trigger Jenkins build via push to a specific branch on GitLab. At this moment I am using GitLab webhooks integration, to run a specific job? Now it starts after the push to any branch, but I need to start a job from push to the specific branch.

Answer (score 3):

Does not appear to be possible currently by selecting a branch in the GitLab webhook. Feel free to watch progress on this new feature in the GitLab issue [Filter web hooks by branch](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20338).

I did note in the issue comments the following that might help you configure things via Jenkins:

> Jenkins GitLab plugin has an option to filter WebHooks by branch. Under `Build Triggers --> Build when a change is pushed to GitLab --> Advanced...`

Comment: This feature is available now. Configure -> Build Triggers -> Advanced -> Filter branches by name